# How create a directional light from a point

Tags: opengl

I try to make a directional light from a lamp in openGL, but I have a big trouble with that.
I set the light positon to the lamp, but there is no the directional light effect.
I have normals specified.
In addition, there is an issue with colours of the objects while the lighting is enabled. I tried to set glMaterial, but the light effect hide out than.
How it should be done?

My code is here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h> 
#include "glew.h"                                        
#include "tex.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

const float pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

class Camera
{
public:
    static double alfa;
    static double wysokosc;
    static double wzrostAlfa;
    static double wzrostWysokosci;
    static double zoom;

    static void ustaw()
    {
        glScalef(zoom, zoom, zoom);
    }

    static void powieksz()
    {
        zoom += 0.25;
    }

    static void pomniejsz()
    {
        if (zoom <= 1)
        {
            zoom = 1;
            return;
        }
        zoom -= 0.25;
    }

    static double x() 
    {
        return 20 * sin(pi * alfa / 180.0);
    }

    static double y() 
    {
        return wysokosc;
    }

    static double z() 
    {
        return 20 * cos(pi * alfa / 180.0);
    }

    static void Prawo()
    {
        alfa += wzrostAlfa;
    }

    static void Lewo() 
    {
        alfa -= wzrostAlfa;
    }

    static void Gora()
    {
        wysokosc += wzrostWysokosci;
    }

    static void Dol() 
    {
        wysokosc -= wzrostWysokosci;
    }
};

class RuchomaFigura
{
protected:
    double promien;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    float predkosc;
    int *tekstura;
    int kat;

public:
    /*
    *   r - promien
    *   p - maksymalna wysokosc unoszenia
    *   x, z - 'x' i 'z' z polozenia
    *   k - kierunek ruchu
    *   pr - predkosc ruchu
    */
    RuchomaFigura(double r, int *t, double x, double z, float pr):
        promien(r), tekstura(t), predkosc(pr), x(x), z(z) { }

    void odswiez() 
    {
        if (kat < 360)
        {
            kat += predkosc;
        }
        else
        {
            kat = predkosc;
        }

        glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(kat, 0, 1, 0);
            rysuj();
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    virtual void rysuj() = 0;
};

class Pilka : public RuchomaFigura 
{
public:
    Pilka(double r, int *t, double x, double z, float pr):
      RuchomaFigura(r, t, x, z, pr) { }

    void rysuj()
    {
        GLUquadric *obiekt = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obiekt, GL_TRUE);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tekstura);
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE); 
        gluSphere(obiekt, promien, 30, 30);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
};

double Camera::alfa = 0;
double Camera::wysokosc = 3;
double Camera::wzrostAlfa = 1.5;
double Camera::wzrostWysokosci = 0.5;
double Camera::zoom = 1;

int textures[5];

Pilka balls[] = {
    Pilka(0.4, &textures[2], 3.5, 3.5, 2),
};

void uklad()
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //zielona oś X
        glVertex3f(-5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(5.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // niebieska oś Y
        glVertex3f(0.0, -5.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,  5.0, 0.0);

        glColor3f(0.7,  0.7, 0.7); // czarna oś Z
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0,  5.0);
    glEnd();
}

void prostopadloscian(float x, float y, float z, float red, float green, float blue)
{
    glColor3f(red, green, blue);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glNormal3f(0,1,0);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glNormal3f(-1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glNormal3f(0,0,-1);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);        
        glNormal3f(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,-z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glNormal3f(0,0,1);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);
    glEnd();
}

void krzeslo()
{
    // nogi krzesla
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.8, 0, 0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.8, 0, 0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.8, 0, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.8, 0, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    // siedzenie
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.101, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(1, 0.1, 1, 0.65, 0.50, 0.39);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.201, 0.0);
    // oparcie
    // krawedzie boczne oparcia
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.8, 2.0, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.8, 2.0, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    // dolna krawedz oparcia
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.85, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    // tralki krzesla
    // tralka srodkowa
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.0, 2.35, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.05, 0.4, 0.05, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.4, 2.35, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.05, 0.4, 0.05, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.4, 2.35, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.05, 0.4, 0.05, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    // tralki krzesla

    // gorna krawedz oparcia
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 2.85, -0.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.7,0.1,0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    // koniec oparcia
    glPopMatrix();
}

void szafa()
{
    // rama 
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, -3.0, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(1.3, 0.1, 1.0, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 3.0, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(1.3, 0.1, 1.0, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-1.2, 0.0, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 3.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(1.2, 0.0, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 3.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    // tylna sciana
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -0.9);
        prostopadloscian(1.1, 2.9, 0.1, 0.59, 0.41, 0.31);
    glPopMatrix();


    // przednia część
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.2, 0.0, 1.7);
        glRotatef(-30.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(1.1, 2.9, 0.1, 0.91, 0.76, 0.65);
    glPopMatrix();


    // uchwyt
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.5, 0.0, 2.2);
        glRotatef(-30.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void stolik()
{
    // nogi
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.8, 0, 1.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.4, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.8, 0, 1.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.4, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.8, 0, -1.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.4, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.8, 0, -1.8);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 1.4, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    // blat
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.5, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(1, 0.1, 2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    // zeszyt
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.701, 1.0);
        glRotatef(50.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.81, 0.71, 0.23);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void lozko()
{
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-1.6, 0, 4.6);
        prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(1.6, 0, 4.6);
        prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-1.6, 0, -4.6);
        prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(1.6, 0, -4.6);
        prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.559, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(2,0.3,5,0.85,0.85,0.95);
    glPopMatrix();


    // poduszki
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.1, -4.0);
        prostopadloscian(1.3,0.2,0.6,0.137255,0.419608,0.556863);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.1, 4.0);
        prostopadloscian(1.3,0.2,0.6,0.137255,0.419608,0.556863);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void polka()
{
    glPushMatrix();
        prostopadloscian(2.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-2.6, 0, 0);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(2.6, 0, 0);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
    glPopMatrix();

    // ksiazki
    // pierwsza od lewej
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-1.5, 0.601, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.59, 0.41, 0.31);
    glPopMatrix();
    // druga
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-1.0, 0.601, 0.0);
        prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPopMatrix();
    // ostatnia
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.45, 0.601, 0.0);
        glRotatef(30.0, 0, 0, 1);
        prostopadloscian(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.81, 0.71, 0.23);
    glPopMatrix();
}


void lampa()
{
    glPushMatrix();
        prostopadloscian(0.05, 1.0, 0.05, 0.5f, 0.35f, 0.05f);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, -1.2, 0);
        prostopadloscian(0.7, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void lampka()
{
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.01, 0);
        prostopadloscian(0.3, 0.05, 0.2, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.651, 0);
        prostopadloscian(0.05, 0.6, 0.05, 0.90, 0.91, 0.98);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.651, 0);
        prostopadloscian(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.91, 0.76, 0.65);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void obraz()
{
    // Ramka
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, -2.0, -7.8);
        glPushMatrix();
            prostopadloscian(2.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
            glTranslatef(0.0, 4.1, 0.0);
            prostopadloscian(2.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
            glTranslatef(-2.0, -2.1, 0.0);
            prostopadloscian(0.1, 2.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
            glTranslatef(4.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            prostopadloscian(0.1, 2.0, 0.1, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    // Obraz
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[4]);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glNormal3f(0,0,1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex3f(-1.9,-1.9,-7.7);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex3f(-1.9,2,-7.7);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex3f(1.9,2,-7.7);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex3f(1.9,-1.9,-7.7);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void pokoj()
{
    // Podłoga
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glNormal3f(0,1,0);
        glTexCoord2f(-5,-8);
        glVertex3f(-5,-5,-8);
        glTexCoord2f(5,-8);
        glVertex3f(5,-5,-8);
        glTexCoord2f(5,8);
        glVertex3f(5,-5,8);
        glTexCoord2f(-5,8);
        glVertex3f(-5,-5,8);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        // Ściana przy łózku
        glColor3f(0.847059, 0.847059, 0.74902);
        glNormal3f(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(-5,5,8);
        glVertex3f(-5,-5,8);
        glVertex3f(-5,-5,-8);
        glVertex3f(-5,5,-8);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        // Ściana z obrazem
        glColor3f(0.867059, 0.857059, 0.75902);
        glNormal3f(0,0,1);
        glVertex3f(-5,-5,-8);
        glVertex3f(5,-5,-8);
        glVertex3f(5,5,-8);
        glVertex3f(-5,5,-8);
    glEnd();
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //kolor tła okna
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective(60.0, 1.0, 1.0, 20.0); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // nic więcej na stosie rzutowania
                                // się nie znajdzie   
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    float lightPosition[] = { 0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    float lightDirection[] = { 0.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection);

    textures[0] = setTexture("floor.bmp", GL_REPLACE);
    textures[1] = setTexture("basketball.bmp", GL_REPLACE);
    textures[2] = setTexture("football.bmp", GL_REPLACE);

    textures[4] = setTexture("obraz.bmp", GL_REPLACE);
}

void display() 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(Camera::x(), Camera::y(), Camera::z(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    Camera::ustaw();

    // uklad();

    pokoj();

    obraz();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-2.999, -4.749, 2.0);
        lozko();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glTranslatef(-2.0, 0.5, -4.499);
        polka();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(98.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glTranslatef(3.5, -3.999, 3.0);
        krzeslo();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(4.0, -3.599, -4.0);
        stolik();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 4.0, 0.0);
        lampa();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(4.5, -1.95, -5.0);
        lampka();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glTranslatef(5.5, -1.85, -3.9);
        szafa();
    glPopMatrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof balls / sizeof(Pilka); i++) 
    {
        balls[i].odswiez();
    }

    // linka od piłki
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.401, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 2.60, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int v) 
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000/60, timer, v);
}

void reshape(GLint w, GLint h) 
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(40.0, GLfloat(w) / GLfloat(h), 1.0, 150.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void klawiatura(unsigned char znak, int, int) 
{
    switch (znak) 
    {
        case 'e':
            Camera::powieksz();
        break;

        case 'q':
            Camera::pomniejsz();
        break;

        case 'a': 
            Camera::Lewo(); 
        break;

        case 'd':
            Camera::Prawo();  
        break;

        case 'w': 
            Camera::Gora();
        break;

        case 's':
            Camera::Dol();
        break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, args);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(80, 80);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Projekt");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(klawiatura);  
    glutTimerFunc(100, timer, 0);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the issue? Can you post some screenshots/diagrams of what you want vs what you have?

Comment: I would like to have someting like that http://dudka.cz/rrv/files/screenshot/room4-step079-snapshot000.png?action=fullImage   but I have only two lamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't see that you're setting the light color anywhere. By default, GL_SPECULAR is set to `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` and `GL_AMBIENT` and `GL_DIFFUSE` are set to `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. Unless you have a specular component to your material, you won't see any change. You should at least set `GL_DIFFUSE` to something meaningful.

Second, if you're expecting a spotlight effect that, for example, creates a circle of light on the floor, you'll want to set `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF` to some small angle. By default it's 180 degrees, which gives you a 360-degree "cone" of light.

See: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html#name4

Comment: I added two lights. The code is here http://pastebin.com/sZAvbS2i. Looks much better, but there is still an issue with colours. Please look at http://postimage.org/image/cyexntvff/   the objects on the bed should be blue for example. Walls too.

Comment: @daroPL - The pillows are a dark greenish-blue, but you're lighting them with a bright yellow light, so you get green. Try adding a dim white ambient light (rgb about 0.1 or 0.2) and see what happens. In fact, you might want to disable the other two lights temporarily to see what colors the ambient light gives you.

Comment: I added ambient 0.3 for every lamp. It's quite better. Look at http://postimage.org/image/3zha964zr/    but I would like the walls be more lighted and the light on the table be like a torch.

Comment: @daroPL - Ah, actually I was suggesting that you add global ambient light source to your scene. Search for `Global Ambient Light` in the glprogramming link I gave above. This will light the entire scene. Then work on the directional lights.

Comment: Ok. I set the global ambient light to 0.5 and it looks like here http://postimage.org/image/cncq7bsrp/    it's better, but I don't know why there isn't the light effect on the wall next to the bed (despite the light is something around the lamp) - the wall have only one colour? The same is on the table and the table-lamp. Should I specific shininess or something?

Comment: @daroPL - Yes, you will want to specify the material properties. You also need to check the geometry of your lamp and the wall. If I'm reading your source code correctly, the bottom of the wall by the bed is 60 degrees away from the the light, so you would have to set GL_SPOT_CUTOFF to something greater than 60 in order to see its effect on the wall. Here's an experiment: What happens if you temporarily set the direction for LIGHT0 to point directly at the wall (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)?

Comment: Perfectly with the 60 degrees! Will it be the same with the lamp on the table? I changed its to 20 degrees and a light of the lamp goes away than and appears about 30 degrees. However, the light effect isn't like a torch, specific for a lamp like that (circle of light on the table)

Comment: @daroPL - Try playing with the material properties of the table: ambient, diffuse, specular and shininess.

Comment: I use GL_COLOR_MATERIAL. However, I've added the material properties http://pastebin.com/keUdmav9 and there is no light effect then.

Comment: I fixed it and I have questions about things circled on the screenshot only http://postimage.org/image/u3d3it72b/    I'm right that is caused that I haven't added shadows for these things yet?

Comment: @daroPL - What does the global ambient light do?

Comment: `GLfloat global_ambient[] = {0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f};`

Comment: @daroPL - What I mean to ask is, what does ambient light mean? I think if you spent some time learning what the different types of lights do, and then experimented with different values to see what happens, you would have much more success getting the effects you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to specify GL_SPOT_DIRECTION for a directional light, which cannot be a spot light.  Since you say "make a directional light from a lamp", I am not sure you understand that a directional light is infinitely far away, like the sun.

Comment: Okay, so in this case how I should call a light of the torch? What kind of light is it?

Comment: @daroPL:  That depends on which meaning of "torch" you use.  If you are using the word as a British person would, to refer to a battery-powered device that projects a beam of light, I would call that a spot light.  If you mean some burning material attached to a stick, I'd call that a point light.  In either case, the light radiates out from one point, so the light rays do not all travel in the same direction, and it is not a directional light.

Comment: I mean a battery-powered device :).

Comment: OK, we Americans call that a "flashlight". :-)